# No mouse icon when using remote input KDEConnect

Tags: 18.04, mouse, icons, remote, kde-connect

I am trying to remote control my laptop using KDEConnect. It works, in the sense that it changes the mouse location, but the mouse icon remains in the same place, giving no indication where I am at the screen of my laptop.

My laptop have Ubuntu 18.04 version, and my phone is a Huawei Mate 10 Pro with the latest EMUI.

Comment: Interesting, I had not used this feature in some years and it used to work without problems but I have the same issue on KUbunui 18.04 with nvidia graphics

Comment: Mmm, the other features work fine. I also have nvida card but use the integrated graphics. I read on another post that a possible fix was to reinstall gnome and x-wayland, but seemed like a lot of hassle...

Comment: I do not use GNOME, I am on Kubuntu and I also don't have x-wayland installed (Kubuntu 18.04 does not use Wayland. I all check tomorrow how it behaves on my 20.04 Intel graphics kubuntu.

Comment: Works fine on the Intel graphics 20.04.